# Berkeley AI Course Question on Nearly Zero Sum Games

Tags: research

I am drawing this question from Berkeley's AI course (also not sure if it is the correct place to ask, so I apologize ahead of time)
https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs188/pacman/course_schedule.html

Currently, I am working on section 3's Homework.

My question is: the question (Part 1, question 6). Why is it that we can only guarantee that if the Min agent acts suboptimally, the best we can hope for is the following [image]

It seems that we can put any arbitrary value for the second node e.g. whey does it have to be -Episolon. It could be any range of values, e.g. Epsilon, in which case we would have optimised the Player A

Comment: Try to summarize your research question;please!

Comment: The question is very simple - why does A's outcome on the second branch have to be minus epsilon? Couldn't it be any random number?

Answer (score 3):

(using X for epsilon because keyboard)

This is just a hypothesis, but if you have a maximising agent and a minimising agent, then the optimal outcome for A (maximising) is to sweep the board (X,0), while the optimal outcome for B (minimising) is (-X,0) because B is minimising A's score, not their own.

A's optimal outcome is then complicated by the factor for sub-optimality, which we then imagine approaches zero.

There seem to be a bunch of assumptions that are not articulated, though, if this hypothesis is true.